# NWJS Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'mdns'

Tags: node.js, module, mdns, nwjs

I have not so much experience with nwjs. If I open my nwjs.app I found this error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'mdns'
I try to fix it removing node modules and reinstall npm but it doesn't work. I tried to remove mdns module and reinstall but nothing.
I tried to change permission to the folders but it doesn't work too.
I don't found causes and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: With another version of nwjs in console I have this error:Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'mdns'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:494:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:522:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at self.require (<anonymous>:11:26)

Comment: what os are you on? and have you tried with a clean app/package?

Comment: I have Sierra. I haven't a clean app/package. I'm new in Node. Can you suggest me some module to clean and maitain the rights version of the modules, please? Thank you very much

Comment: create a new folder and use `npm init` to create a clean package, when I say clean I mean without any other modules/packages. use npm install to install it in the same folder than require it in your script. this will insure the issue isn't caused by compatibility with other packages. run the test and see what happens. if it used to work before or with other versions I'd look around the issues page on their github

Comment: I'm assuming you're installing mdns using "npm install" right? if you're doing in any other way, please use npm instead and make sure to install it in your app folder. more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdns